# Display hierarchy of data in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, ios8

I'd like to display a hierarchy of data in my iOS 8 app. It is actually for displaying comments from a website (see screenshots).

I thought about using a UITableView, but it doesn't seemed to be design for this use. Is there a better UI control I should use or custom one that is made for this?

[image]

Here is how the data looks like for extra context (notice the `parent` node is what creates the hierarchy):
[image]

Comment: Table views have the ability to use different indentation levels for different cells. The delegate controls this behavior.

Comment: It could get really messy tho because it's not just indentation, but sorting by parents, then sub-sorting children of each, then injecting rows below certain rows. It seems like a painful hack unless there is something in the API that is "aware" of hierarchical data.

Comment: That would get into your data model and how you convert it to the cells. You could represent each level of indentation as a different section. Not ideal, but an option. Managing inserting of rows is always a challenge. However, if every level is a new section you are always just inserting at the end of a section.